# How can I select one item from data in json array by id in NEXT.js

Tags: json, fetch, next.js

I'm very new to Next.js and are fetching data from an api. I have a list of movies and I want to select one movie and show that movies image on a new page. I guess I have to use the objects id, but I don't know how. This is what I have so far:

Here is my code from starting page:

```
<div className="movies">
      {props.movies.map(movie => (
        <div>
          <p>{movie.name}</p>
          <Link href={`/detailPage?movieId=${movie.image}`}>
            <img src={movie.image}></img>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
```

And here is the code from detail page:

```
 <section>
        <div>
          <img src={movieId.image}></img>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started Follow this tutorial. The section on dinamic pages has your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the object you are trying to display from the array. You can do something like this:

```jsx
const movie = props.movies.find((m) => m.id === idOfTheMovieYouWant);

return (
  <section>
    <div>
      <img src={movie.image} />
    </div>
  </section>
);
```